# What are the different ways of writing "if" conditional statements using PHP?

Tags: php

What are the different ways of writing if conditional statements using PHP?

I know for example of the following

```
if($test == 1){
}else{
}
```

and

```
if($test == 1)
   echo 'asdsa';
else
   echo 'sdaaa';
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's the [alternative control structure syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

```
if ($text == 1):
    echo 'asdsa';
else:
   echo 'asdsa';
endif;
```

Comment: This is useful to use in views (the V in MVC). It makes things slightly easier to read (you can tell exactly which control structure is closing etc).

Comment: Heh. I just remembered the alternative control structure syntax and added that to my post. I haven't used it very often, since I usually write back-end (non-view) modules, but I have used it in views.

Comment: man, i hate this syntax. There's probably nothing actually wrong with it, but it reminds me of BASIC.

Comment: @nickf Oh BASIC was beautiful! ;)

Answer (score 9):

The other way is to use a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). The example in the PHP documentation is:

```
<?php
// Example usage for: Ternary Operator
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];

// The above is identical to this if/else statement
if (empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = 'default';
} else {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
}

?>
```

The other [control structures are documented in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) as well. The only conditional statements are the ternary conditional operator, `if` (and `else`), and `elseif` or `else if`. However, they do have [an alternative syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Answer (score 7):

```
echo ($test == 1) ? 'asdsa' : 'sdaaa';
```

Comment: I was worried someone might forget this one. This is my favorite, because I'm not allowed to use it at work :D

Comment: That’s not a statement, that’s just an expression.

Answer (score 5):

Besides what's already been said, there's stuff like

```
$sql_link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root') or die('no mysql');
```

Or like [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

(the assignment "OR" trick is really a trick :) if the mysql_connect() doesn't evaulate to true, PHP will try to evaluate the second expression so this is really a hack of:

```
if (mysql_connect('localhost', 'root')) {
    $sql_link = true;
}
else {
    die('no mysql');
}
```

)

Comment: +1 I totally forgot about "or" in PHP .. never use it anymore but years ago it was all over my code.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that "Conditional Complexity" is a code smell. [Polymorphism](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html) is your friend.

> Conditional logic is innocent in its infancy, when it’s simple to understand and contained within a
>   few lines of code. Unfortunately, it rarely ages well. You implement several new features and
>   suddenly your conditional logic becomes complicated and expansive. [Joshua Kerevsky: Refactoring to Patterns]

One of the simplest things you can do to avoid nested if blocks is to learn to use [Guard Clauses](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html).  (Note: this is not PHP syntax.  Regard it as pseudo code.  The techniques here are what are important.)

```
double getPayAmount() {
if (_isDead) return deadAmount();
if (_isSeparated) return separatedAmount();
if (_isRetired) return retiredAmount();
return normalPayAmount();
};
```

The other thing I have found simplifies things pretty well, and which makes your code self-documenting, is [Consolidating conditionals](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/consolidateConditionalExpression.html).

```
double disabilityAmount() {
    if (isNotEligableForDisability()) return 0;
    // compute the disability amount
```

Other valuable [refactoring](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/) techniques associated with conditional expressions include [Decompose Conditional](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/decomposeConditional.html), [Replace Conditional with Visitor](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithVisitor.html), and [Reverse Conditional](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/reverseConditional.html).

Now that you have some new hammers, don't let everything look like a nail!

Comment: taking an early return (i.e. in the middle of a function) is what I call bad practice and very error prone. probably not in PHP, but if you use it in other languages you might end up leaking memory, etc.

use a switch instead.

Comment: p.s: using an early return in a switch is also bad. I just meant to simplify your code (and make it maintainable) by using a switch.

Comment: @MiRAGe: You are reciting Dijkstra's SESE (single entry, single exit) dictum from "Structured Programming."  See here for a discussion: http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2008/03/07/single-entry-single-exit-should-it-still-be-applicable-in-object-oriented-languages.aspx.

Answer (score 4):

The standard if statement:

```
if(expression) {
    // code
} elseif(expression) {
    // code
} else {
    // code
}
```

Without braces for single lines of code after each statement:

```
if(expression)
    // single line of code
elseif(expression)
    // single line of code
else
    // single line of code
```

The alternate control syntax:

```
if(expression):
    // code
elseif(expression):
    // code
else:
    // code
endif;
```

And finally, the ternary operator:

```
(expression ? expression_if_true : expression_if_false);
```

Which can also be written as:

```
(expression) ? expression_if_true : expression_if_false;
```

Or without brackets entirely if you wish.

Comment: this should be the accepted anser as it covers pretty much all of the available options

Answer (score 3):

```
if($test == 1){
}else{
}

# can only be used if performing 1 line of code after statement
if($test == 1)
   echo 'asdsa';
else
   echo 'sdaaa';

#you can have as many elseif as you like (but you may wish to check out switch see below:
if($test == 1){
}elseif{
}else{
}
```

Also take a look at switch() http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

```
switch($test)
{
    case "1" :
        break;
    case "2" :
        break;
    default :
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

```
<?php
if ($a == 5):
    echo "a equals 5";
    echo "...";
elseif ($a == 6):
    echo "a equals 6";
    echo "!!!";
else:
    echo "a is neither 5 nor 6";
endif;
?>
```