# How to set/overwrite variable if expression is true without repeating variable name in PHP

Tags: php, conditional-statements, bit-manipulation

I thought I'd seen this before, but I'm not finding it anywhere.

If I have a variable and want to assign it a new value if a condition is true, but otherwise leave the variable alone, is there a way to do this without repeating the variable/original value?

The "long ways" would be:

```
if($condition == TRUE) {
     $og_value = "New Value";
}
```

Or:

```
$og_value = ($condition == TRUE) ? "New Value" : $og_value;
```

But I seem to remember there is a trick, either built into assignment operators or using bitwise operators to only set `$og_value` if `$condition` is true, otherwise it short circuits and leaves `$og_value` as it was before the assignment/comparison.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortest way to assign a default value to a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761910/shortest-way-to-assign-a-default-value-to-a-variable)

Comment: Subsumed by [What are the different ways of writing “if” conditional statements using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1594526/90527), in particular [Tom's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1594557/90527)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for:

```
$condition && $og_value = "New Value";
```

Comment: This is correct, but let me just address the OP and say that this is atrocious and he should never use this.

Comment: @RafeKettler - Atrocious to look at or actually bad practice/anti-pattern?

Comment: @stewe - Thanks! But that looks like it sets them both (even if it doesn't). Is that what makes it atrocious like Rafe says?

Comment: @RafeKettler Well, the first thing I noticed is that the order matters, which makes sense, but it took me 5 minutes to figure out why it wasn't working. Second thing is, I still have to repeat the variable name if I just want to set it's value if it's not already set, with the above it would be `!$og_value && $og_value = "default";` And that is atrocious even to me.

Comment: @Anthony: An `if`-statement is the best choice because everything else may lead to confusion about what the program really does (maybe you experienced that ^^). Especially if the code gets bigger, with lots of people working on it, readability becomes more and more important.

Comment: @stewe: the goal is to keep it simple and clean, and even though the if statement is less confusing, I've always found that nested-ifs, especially for "and if this value is set" or what have you, is actually harder to follow. Not because it's confusing, but just because I start to feel my head do this kind of bouncy ball thing, like I'm reading "Meet Dick and Jane".  In my case, I have 2 conditions, creating 4 outcomes, so in the interest of readability and coherence, I've gone with : `$current_value = ($flag) ? $current_value : $new_value; $current_value = ?: $default_value;`

Comment: The first one says "if condition A is set, don't touch the variable, if it is not set, overwrite." thus leaving it alone for the second statement : "if value is empty, use default". This is cleaner than having a nested if, which I think logically was easiest to follow, but  felt like I was telling a much bigger story of how this value gets assigned, whereas the two lines, I think, get right to the point.